# Extract negative value from regex

Tags: node.js, regex

The Regex is:

```
pattern = new RegExp(/coordinates\([-+]?(\d+(\.\d+)?) [-+]?(\d+(\.\d+)?)\)/i)
```

Test:

```
pattern.exec('coordinates(1.5421245 23.243545689)')
```

results:

```
["coordinates(1.5421245 23.243545689)", "1.5421245", ".5421245", "23.243545689", ".243545689", index: 0, input: "coordinates(1.5421245 23.243545689)", groups: undefined]
```

and I can extract the points from index 1 and 3 as `1.5421245` and `23.243545689`.

But for one or more negative numbers, it is not extracting the correct numbers.

Ex.    `pattern.exec('coordinates(1.5421245 -23.243545689)')` returns

```
["coordinates(1.5421245 -23.243545689)", "1.5421245", ".5421245", "23.243545689", ".243545689", index: 0, input: "coordinates(1.5421245 -23.243545689)", groups: undefined]
```

Comment: Capture the signs, use `/coordinates\(([-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?) ([-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\)/i` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/x7Yi6Q/1))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the open parenthesis to the left to also include the plus or minus sign, and use

```js
/coordinates\(([-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?) ([-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\)/i
/coordinates\(([-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+([-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\)/i
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x7Yi6Q/1). Note that now, all your required values are in Group 1 and Group 2, no redundant groups since the `(\.\d+)?` (capturing group) is now a *non-capturing* group, `(?:\.\d+)?`.

The `\s+` pattern matches one or more whitespaces, which can be useful if the text is not always formatted with a single space.